# Did you manage to run STBuffer on MULTIPOLYGONS ? With SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlgeography

In SQL Server geo-spatial I can't run a `STBuffer` for `MULTIPOLYGONS`.

```
DECLARE @g geography = geography::STMPolyFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((1 1, 1 -1, -1 -1, -1 1, 1 1)),((1 1, 3 1, 3 3, 1 1)))', 4326);  

SELECT @g   -- no problem to run
SELECT @g.ToString()  -- no problem to run
SELECT @g.STBuffer(1).ToString();  -- error
```

The error returned is:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 64
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined
>   routine or aggregate "geography":
>
> System.ArgumentException: 24144: This operation cannot be completed
>   because the instance is not valid. Use MakeValid to convert the
>   instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points
>   of a geometry instance to shift slightly. System.ArgumentException:

Comment: `Select @g.STIsValid();` running this query returns `0` - so your spatial type is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is happening because the polygons you are creating are not valid `geography` polygons. Try creating the Multi Polygons using a valid set of Latitude/Longitude values.

Executing the same code with `geometry` data type seems to work.

```
DECLARE @g geometry = geometry::STMPolyFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((1 1, 1 -1, -1 -1, -1 1, 1 1)),((1 1, 3 1, 3 3, 1 1)))', 4326);  

select 
    geoMultiPolys = @g, 
    geoMultiPolysString = @g.ToString(),
    buffered = @g.STBuffer(1),
    bufferedString = @g.STBuffer(1).ToString(),
    IsValid = @g.STIsValid()
```

[image: Results]

[image: Buffered Spatial Polygon]

Similarly this one works for geography

```
DECLARE @g geography = geography::STMPolyFromText('MULTIPOLYGON (((40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40)), ((20 35, 10 30, 10 10, 30 5, 45 20, 20 35), (30 20, 20 15, 20 25, 30 20)))', 4326);  

select 
    geoMultiPolys = @g, 
    geoMultiPolysString = @g.ToString(),
    buffered = @g.STBuffer(1),
    bufferedString = @g.STBuffer(1).ToString(),
    IsValid = @g.STIsValid()
```

[image: valid SQL geography]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll figure out some of the issues I have migrating Geography data/scripts from Postgres to MS SQL.